# Register & Authentication Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

Good afternoon !

I am creating and authenticating with Laravel 5.2 and I have the following problem , I am using Socialite with google for this case , the user could be register correctly but in the authenticacion with this code fails.

Could anyone help to me ?

```
 public function handleProviderCallback(){
        $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
        $usuario = new User();
        $usuario->name=$user->name;
        $usuario->email=$user->email;
        $usuario->password=\Hash::make("1234");
        $usuario->photo=$user->avatar;
        $usuario->role_id=1;
        $usuario->isLocked=0;
        $usuario->save();       
        $findUser= User::where('email','=',$usuario->email)->get();
        if (!$buscarUsuario->isEmpty()) { 
            if (\Auth::attempt(['email' => $findUser[0]->email, 'password' => $findUser[0]->password]))
            {
                 return redirect()->intended('profile');
            }else{
                echo "NO";
                //return \Redirect::back();      
            }

        }else{
            echo "NOTHING";
        }
    }
```

The result doing echo in $buscarUsuario

```
[{"id":81,"name":"Kiko","first_surname":"","last_surname":"","descripcion":"","email":"correo@gmail.com","created_at":"2016-06-04 14:15:07","updated_at":"2016-06-04 14:15:07"}
```

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: did you setup guard in auth.php ?

Comment: This authenticate works if I send the email and passowrd throughout form , but with this form returns no , the password was protected in the model but I need to authenticate.

Comment: What is your error?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Auth::loginUsingId($findUser['id']);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#other-authentication-methods

method for login form ID

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you call `Auth::attempt()`, it is expecting the plaintext password, but you are passing the hashed password. This is why it fails.

Since you have selected the User object and have the ID, you can call `\Auth::loginUsingId()` like below.

Also, you are calling `isEmpty()` on `$buscarUsuario`, which doesn't appear to exist. That should be `$findUser`.

```
if(!$findUser->isEmpty()){
    if (\Auth::loginUsingId($findUser[0]->id))
    {
         return redirect()->intended('profile');
    }else{
        echo "NO";
        //return \Redirect::back();      
    }
 } else {
     echo "NO";
 }
```